# What is the Gensim word2vec output

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I want to use gensim word2vec as input for neural network. I have 2 questions:

1) gensim.models.Word2Vec get as parameter the size. How this parameter is used? and size of what?

2) Once trained what is the output of gensim word2vec? As i could see this is not a probability values (not between 0 and 1). It seems to me for each word vector we get a distance (cosinus) between this word and some other words (but which words exactly?)

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4):

Ans to 1 -> The size parameter is the dimension of the word vectors i.e. each vector will be having 100 dimensions if `size=100`

Ans to 2 -> You can save the word vectors using this function `save_word2vec_format(fname="vectors.txt", fvocab=None, binary=False)` [ref](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html). This will save a file `"vectors.txt"` which will have first line as `<size of the vocabulary> <dimensions>` and rest of the lines will be of the form `<word> <vector of size dimension>`.

Sample for `"vectors.txt"`:

```
297820 100
the -0.18542234751 0.138813291635 0.0392148854213 0.0238721499736 -0.0443151295365 0.03226302388 -0.168626211895 -0.17397777844 -0.0547546409461 0.166621666046 0.0534506882806 0.0774947957067 -0.180520283779 -0.0938140452702 -0.0354599008902 -0.0533488133527 -0.0667684564816 -0.0210904306995 -0.103069115604 -0.138712344952 -0.035142440978 -0.125067138202 0.0514192233164 -0.142052171747 0.0795726729387 0.0310433094806 -0.00666224898992 0.047268806263 0.0339849190176 -0.181107631029 0.0477396587205 0.0483130822899 -0.090229393762 0.0224528628225 0.190814060668 -0.179506639849 0.00034066604609 0.0639057478 0.156444383949 -0.0366888977431 -0.170674385275 -0.053907152935 0.106572313582 0.0724497821903 -0.00848717936216 0.124053494271 -0.0420715605081 0.0460277422205 -0.0514693485657 0.132215091575 -0.0429308836475 -0.111784875385 -0.0543172053216 0.0849476776796 -0.015301892652 0.00992711997251 -0.00566113637219 0.00136359242972 -0.0382116842516 0.0681229985191 0.0685156463052 0.0759072640845 -0.0238136705161 0.168710450161 0.00879930186352 -0.179756801973 -0.210286559709 -0.161832152064 -0.0212640125813 -0.0115905356526 -0.0949562511822 0.126493155131 0.0215821686774 -0.164276918273 -0.0573806470616 -0.0147266125919 0.0566350339785 -0.0276969849679 0.0178970346094 0.0599163813161 0.0919867942845 0.172071394538 0.0714226787026 0.109037733251 0.00403647493576 0.044853743905 -0.0915639785243 -0.0242494817113 0.0705554654776 0.255584701079 0.001309754199 0.0872413719572 -0.0376289782286 0.158184379871 0.109245196088 -0.0727554069742 0.168820215174 0.0454895919746 0.0741726055733 -0.134467710995
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Dimension Size in word2vec**

- Word2vec is used to create a vector space that represents words based on the trained corpus.
- The vector is a mathematical representation of the word compared to other words in the given corpus. The dimensions size is the vector length.
- Performing mathematical operations on the vectors represent the relationship between words.
- as the vector of "man" and "king" will be close and same for the vector of "Faris" and "France".
- If the size is too small like two or three dimensions, the information representation will be very limited.
- The dimensions can be simplified as a linkage between different words. Words can be linked to each other in different dimensions based on how the words are positioned to each other in the corpus.

> How to use the vectors

- The vector by itself is useless and the numbers represent the position of the word with relations to all other words in the corpus
- The vector can be meaningful when measured against another vector
- cosine similarity is one of the common methods to measure the similarity between different words.

**Good luck**